# Prove that $\alpha \equiv \beta$ iff $\alpha \leftrightarrow \beta$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I need to prove that $\alpha \equiv \beta$ iff $\alpha \leftrightarrow \beta$ in two steps. One would be by assuming $\alpha \equiv \beta$, and the second would be by assuming $\alpha \leftrightarrow \beta$.

The first part is fairly straightforward and I've done it like this:

1. $Mod(\alpha) = Mod(\beta)$, by definition of $\alpha \equiv \beta$.
2. Let $Mod(\alpha) = \{I_1,I_2,...I_n\} = Mod(\beta)$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$, by definition of $Mod$ and point 1.
3. $I_i \models \alpha \land I_i \models \beta$ for $\forall I \in \{I_1,I_2,...I_n\}$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}, i \leq n$, by definition of $Mod$ and point 2.
4. $\alpha \leftrightarrow \beta$, by definition of $\leftrightarrow$ and point 3.

Where I is the interpretation function and Mod is the Model.

I'm struggling with the second part of assuming that $\alpha \leftrightarrow \beta$.
What I've done is like this:

1. Let $\{I_1,I_2,...I_n\}$ be the set of interpretations that holds $I_i \models \alpha \land I_i \models \beta$ for $\forall I \in \{I_1,I_2,...I_n\}$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}, i \leq n$, by definition of $\leftrightarrow$.
2. $I_i \models \alpha \Leftrightarrow I_i \in Mod(\alpha)$ for any but fixed $I$ from $\{I_1,I_2,...I_n\}$, definition of $\models$ and $Mod$.
3. $I_i \models \beta \Leftrightarrow I_i \in Mod(\beta)$ for any but fixed $I$ from $\{I_1,I_2,...I_n\}$, definition of $\models$ and $Mod$.
4. $\{I_1,I_2,...I_n\} \subseteq Mod(\alpha)$, from point 2 and definition of $Mod$.
5. $\{I_1,I_2,...I_n\} \subseteq Mod(\beta)$, from point 3 and definition of $Mod$.

But here I'm stuck because I can't further imply that Mod(a) = Mod(b) just from this.

Maybe I'm overthinking it, but does someone have something in mind how to solve it?

Comment: Maybe some details about the symbols must be needed... What symbol is **logical equivalence** and what is **bi-conditional**? The issue is that: "$\alpha$ and $\beta$ are log.equiv iff the bi.conditional of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is a tautology". In plain language the theorem is easy to undertsand...

Comment: What do you mean? logical equivalence would be $\equiv$ and bi-conditional (bi-implication) would be $\leftrightarrow$

Comment: Perfect; if so, the theorem **must be** $\alpha \equiv \beta \text { iff } \vDash \alpha \leftrightarrow \beta$.

Comment: Yes, but I need to prove that theorem, from both sides of the iff. I can't just assume it. The question is how do I prove this theorem?

Comment: I know :( but they want me to prove it using the models, entailment and interpretation definitions, makes it much harder unfortunately.

Comment: From the definitions, if $v(\alpha\equiv\beta)=1$, then $v(\alpha)=v(\beta)$, hence, $v(\alpha\leftrightarrow\beta)=1$. This is reversible, hence $v(\alpha\equiv\beta)=1$ if, and only if, $v(\alpha\leftrightarrow\beta)=1$ as required.

Comment: Nothing changes... Assume that formula is a TAUT: it means that in every valuation $v: v(\alpha \leftrightarrow \beta)= \text T$ that means that, by truth table of $\leftrightarrow$: $v(\alpha)=v(\beta)$.